# Have a PHP table that is pulling from SQL Server to present table data. I want to add column header filters to the columns to narrow down

Tags: php, sql-server

[image]

The issue I am running into is that the rows in the table are pulling from sql server so they are in php code not in hard code on the php doc. I am still unable to find someone there is a way to filter as in excel filter the column headers to narrow down the search.

I want the whole table displayed at first and then the column headers to be displayed as filters for choosing.

Most of what I have seen is not in PHP code to pull the data out of database and I think that is my problem if rows were already in the table  of the HTML form it might be a little simpler  and I am not using mysql its sqlsrv.

Here is my code.

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <?php 
            include'header.php';
            ?>

            <?php


            $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $dbServer, $connectionInfo);

            $sql = ("SELECT * FROM [Transaction]");
            $query = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
                    $query_display = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);

            if (!$conn) {
                die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . sqlsrv_errors()); 
            }


            //  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM [Transaction]';

            //  $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

            if (!$query) {

                die('An error has occurred. '.print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));
            }


            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="TableFilter/tablefilter_all_min.js"></script>  
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="includes/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>  
            <html>
            <head>
                <title>Transaction / Proposed View</title>
                <style type="text/css">

                    table {
                        margin: auto;
                        font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", "Segoe Ui";
                        font-size: 12px;
                    }

                    h1 {
                        margin: 25px auto 0;
                        text-align: center;
                        text-transform: uppercase;
                        font-size: 17px;
                    }

                    table td {
                        transition: all .5s;
                    }

                    /* Table */
                    .data-table {
                        border-collapse: collapse;
                        font-size: 12px;
                        min-width: 537px;
                    }

                    .data-table th, 
                    .data-table td {
                        border: 1px solid #e1edff;
                        padding: 7px 17px;
                    }
                    .data-table caption {
                        margin: 7px;
                    }

                    /* Table Header */
                    .data-table thead th {
                        background-color: #508abb;
                        color: #FFFFFF;
                        border-color: #6ea1cc !important;
                        text-transform: uppercase;
                    }

                    /* Table Body */
                    .data-table tbody td {
                        color: #353535;
                    }
                    .data-table tbody td:first-child,
                    .data-table tbody td:nth-child(4),
                    .data-table tbody td:last-child {
                        text-align: right;
                    }

                    .data-table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td {
                        background-color: #f4fbff;
                    }
                    .data-table tbody tr:hover td {
                        background-color: #ffffa2;
                        border-color: #ffff0f;
                    }

                    /* Table Footer */
                    .data-table tfoot th {
                        background-color: #e5f5ff;
                        text-align: right;
                    }
                    .data-table tfoot th:first-child {
                        text-align: left;
                    }
                    .data-table tbody td:empty
                    {
                        background-color: #ffcccc;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>

            <body>
            <h1>Transactions</h1>



                <table class="data-table" action="transactions.php" id ="myTable">

                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th onclick="sortTable(0)">ID</th>
                            <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Fund</th>
                            <th onclick="sortTable(2)">Department</th>
                            <th onclick="sortTable(3)">Code</th>
                            <th onclick="sortTable(4)">Year</th>
                            <th onclick="sortTable(5)">Date</th>
                            <th onclick="sortTable(6)">Project</th>
                            <th onclick="sortTable(7)">Description</th>
                            <th onclick="sortTable(8)">Amount</th>
                            <th onclick="sortTable(9)">Detail</th>
                            <th onclick="sortTable(10)">PO</th>
                            <th onclick="sortTable(11)">Type</th>


                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php
                    $transaction_id = 1;

                    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query))
                    {
                        $amount  = $row['amount'] == 0 ? '' : number_format($row['amount']);

                        echo '<tr>
                                <td>'.$transaction_id.'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['fund'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['department'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['code_name'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['budget_year'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['entry_date'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['project_name'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['item_desc'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$amount.'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['detail'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['PO'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['type'].'</td>
                                <td><a href="edit_transaction.php">Edit</a></td>                
                            </tr>';

            //          $total += $row['amount'];
                        $transaction_id++;
                    }?>


                    </tbody>

                </table>






            <script>
            function Feedback() {
                var transaction_id = $("#transaction_id").val();
                var fund = $("#fund").val();
                var department = $("#department").val();
                var code_name = $("#code_name").val();
                var budget_year = $("#budget_year").val();
                var entry_date = $("#entry_date").val();
                var project_name = $("#project_name").val();
                var item_desc = $("#item_desc").val();
                var amount = $("#amount").val();
                var detail = $("#detail").val();
                var PO = $("#PO").val();

                $.post("update.php", { transaction_id: transaction_id, fund: fund, department: department, code_name: code_name, budget_year: budget_year, entry_date: entry_date, project_name: project_name, item_desc: item_desc, amount: amount, detail: detail, PO: PO,},
                function(data) {
               $('#resultfeed').html(data);
               $('#editform')[0].reset();
                });
            }

            </script>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Define "filter".

Comment: I would highly recommend list.js for table filter & search, check it out [here](http://listjs.com)

Comment: @LiamG I am not sure if that will work since the code is coming from the database where as the link you sent has the names and years already in the code.

Comment: @Heidi It will, I have used this with a PHP - SQL integration myself many times. I will provide an example answer

Comment: @Heidi see my answer below

Comment: @LiamG you are the best that did work just as I needed it too -- Thank you

Comment: Thank you again @LiamG now I have to figure out my edit screen and why that will not work and then we will be golden.

Comment: No problem @Heidi ! If you could mark the answer as the selected answer that would be great :) .. post a different question with that problem and put the link in here and I'll take a look and see what I can do

Comment: @LiamG 
here is the other question I had 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50819415/edit-button-to-open-new-window-to-allow-edits-and-update-sql-server-with-php-cod

Comment: @LiamG is there a way to drill down so say if you found all of one department and then want to drill down to a particular date is there a way to drill down 2 times within the search?

Comment: Hmm I'm not too sure, have you tried using the search box feature of list.js and searching for a department and date?

Comment: @LiamG yes it will only search in one column not across in multiple.  So that search does work I have tested that part.

Comment: Have you tried searching for one thing then ordering the other column, for example: search for the date, then order the departments? I know it isn't the perfect solution but other than that I wouldn't know what to suggest

Comment: I have not.  Would I need to order them in the backend?  I was looking more in the beginning to have filters like excel uses with the select all or just choose which ones you wanted selected ex:  department A, B, D not C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="myTable">
<input class="search" placeholder="Search" /><!--Not Required, but useful-->
<table class="data-table" action="transactions.php" id ="myTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="sort" data-sort="id">ID</th>
                        <th class="sort" data-sort="fund">Fund</th>
                        <th class="sort" data-sort="department">Department</th>
                        <th class="sort" data-sort="code">Code</th>
                        <th class="sort" data-sort="year">Year</th>
                        <th class="sort" data-sort="date">Date</th>
                        <th class="sort" data-sort="project">Project</th>
                        <th class="sort" data-sort="description">Description</th>
                        <th class="sort" data-sort="amount">Amount</th>
                        <th class="sort" data-sort="detail">Detail</th>
                        <th class="sort" data-sort="po">PO</th>
                        <th class="sort" data-sort="type">Type</th>


                </thead>
                <tbody class="list">
                <?php
                $transaction_id = 1;

                while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query))
                {
                    $amount  = $row['amount'] == 0 ? '' : number_format($row['amount']);

                    echo '<tr>
                            <td class="id">'.$transaction_id.'</td>
                            <td class="fund">'.$row['fund'].'</td>
                            <td class="department">'.$row['department'].'</td>
                            <td class="code">'.$row['code_name'].'</td>
                            <td class="year">'.$row['budget_year'].'</td>
                            <td class="date">'.$row['entry_date'].'</td>
                            <td class="project">'.$row['project_name'].'</td>
                            <td class="description">'.$row['item_desc'].'</td>
                            <td class="amount">'.$amount.'</td>
                            <td class="detail">'.$row['detail'].'</td>
                            <td class="po">'.$row['PO'].'</td>
                            <td class="type">'.$row['type'].'</td>
                            <td><a href="edit_transaction.php">Edit</a></td>                
                        </tr>';

        //          $total += $row['amount'];
                    $transaction_id++;
                }?>


                </tbody>

            </table>
   </div>
```

and then in your JavaScript:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.5.0/list.min.js"></script>
<script>
var options = {
                valueNames: [
                    'id',
                    'fund',
                    'department',
                    'code',
                    'year',
                    'date',
                    'project',
                    'description',
                    'amount',
                    'detail',
                    'po',
                    'type'
                ]
            };
var userList = new List('myTable', options);
</script>
```