# Edit Button to open new window to allow edits and update Sql Server with PHP code

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

Still learning PHP so this maybe kind the same as others but having issues. 
I want to click edit on the previous screen and it open a Update Record window (below) when that window opens it will have the previous criteria selected but allowing the user to change the records. I have multiple drop down list in the update screen as the departments and things are pulling from other SQL Server tables.  It is not allowing me to put them all in drop down list in order to select new criteria if needed for the update record.

I am just unsure of the code that I may need to use as the starting record page is set up with drop downs pulling from sql server in php code and it works. Not sure why this will not pull the information from the view screen when edit is selected to pull up what transaction and the criteria already chosen.

```
<?php
require('dbcon.php');
include("header.php");
$transaction_id = $_REQUEST['transaction_id'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM [Transaction]where 
transaction_id='" . $transaction_id . "'";
$query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
$query_display = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Update Transaction</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="form">
            <h1>Update Transaction</h1>
            <?php
            $status = "";
            if (isset($_POST['new']) && $_POST['new'] == 1) {
                $transaction_id = $_REQUEST['transaction_id'];
                $fund = $_REQUEST['fund'];
                $department = $_REQUEST['department'];
                $code_name = $_REQUEST['code_name'];
                $budget_year = $_REQUEST['budget_year'];
                $entry_date = $_REQUEST['entry_date'];
                $project_name = $_REQUEST['project_name'];
                $item_desc = $_REQUEST['item_desc'];
                $amount = $_REQUEST['amount'];
                $detail = $_REQUEST['detail'];
                $PO = $_REQUEST['PO'];
                $modified = $_REQUEST['modified'];

                $update = "update [Transaction] set 
    fund='" . $fund . "',
    department='" . $department . "',
    code_name='" . $code_name . "',
    budget_year='" . $budget_year . "',
    entry_date='" . $entry_date . "',
    project_name='" . $project_name . "',
    item_desc='" . $item_desc . "',
    amount='" . $amount . "',
    detail='" . $detail . "',
    PO='" . $PO . "'        

    where transaction_id='" . $transaction_id . "'";
                sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
                $status = "Record Updated Successfully. </br></br>
    <a href='transactions.php'>View Updated Record</a>";
                echo '<p style="color:#FF0000;">' . $status . '</p>';
            } else {
                ?>
                <div>
                    <form name="form" method="post" action=""> 
                        <input type="hidden" name="new" value="1" />
                        <input name="transaction_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['transaction_id']; ?>" />

                        <p>Fund:
                            <?php
                            echo "<select name= 'fund' class='form-control selectpicker' onChange='getState(this.value)' Required>";

                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM  Funding";
                            $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
                            $query_display = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

                            while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query_display, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                if ($row['fund'] == "Operational") {
                                    $selected = ' selected="selected"';
                                } else {
                                    $selected = "";
                                }
                                echo '<option value=" ' . $row['fund'] . '"' . (($row['fund'] == "Operational") ? ' selected="selected"' : "") . '>' . $row['fund'] . '</option>';
                                echo '<option value= " ' . $row['fund'] . ' ">' . $row['fund'] . '</option>';

                                continue;
                            }
                            ?>
                        </p>

                        <p>Department: 

                            <?php
                            echo "<select name= 'department' class='form-control selectpicker' onChange='getState(this.value)' Required>";

                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM Department";
                            $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
                            $query_display = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

                            while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query_display, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                echo "<option selected='selected' value='" . $row['department'] . "'>" . $row['department'] . '</option>';
                                continue;
                            }

                            echo "<option value='" . $row['department'] . "'>" . $row['department'] . '</option>';
                            ?>

                        </p>


                        <p>Object Code:
                            <?php
                            echo "<select name= 'code_name' class='form-control selectpicker' onChange='getState(this.value)' Required>";
                            echo '<option value="$code_name">' . '--Select Object Code' . '</option>';
                            $sql = "SELECT code_name FROM Object_Code";
                            $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
                            $query_display = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
                            while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query_display, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                echo "<option selected='selected' value='" . $row['code_name'] . "'>" . $row['code_name'] . '</option>';
                                continue;
                            }

                            echo "<option value='" . $row['code_name'] . "'>" . $row['code_name'] . '</option>';
                            ?>
                        </p>

                        <p>Budget Year:
                            <select name= 'budget_year' class='form-control selectpicker' onChange='getState(this.value)' Required>
                                <option selected="selected" value="2018-2019">2018-2019</option>
                                <option value="2017-2018">2017-2018</option>
                                <option value="2019-2020">2019-2020</option>
                                <option value="2020-2021">2020-2021</option>
                                <option value="2021-2022">2021-2022</option>
                                <option value="2022-2023">2022-2023</option>
                                <option value="2023-2024">2023-2024</option>
                                <option value="2024-2025">2024-2025</option>
                                <option value="2025-2026">2025-2026</option>
                                <option value="2026-2027">2026-2027</option>
                                <option value="2027-2028">2027-2028</option>
                                <option value="2028-2029">2028-2029</option>
                                <option value="2029-2030">2029-2030</option>
                            </select>
                        </p>

                        <p>Transaction Entry Date:
                            <input type="date" name="entry_date" />
                        </p>


                        <p>Project:
                            <?php
                            echo "<select name= 'project_name' class='form-control selectpicker' onChange='getState(this.value)' Required>";

                            $sql = "SELECT project_name FROM Project";
                            $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
                            $query_display = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
                            while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query_display, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                echo '<option value=" ' . $row['project_name'] . ' ">' . $row['project_name'] . '</option>';
                                continue;
                            }
                            ?>
                        </p>


                        <p>Description:
                            <input type="text" name="item_desc">
                        </p>


                        <p>Amount:
                            <input type="number" name="amount" min="0" max="9999999" step="0.01" size ="7" />
                        </p>


                        <p>Detail:
                        <td><textarea name="detail"></textarea>
                            </p>

                            <p>PO:
                                <input type="text" name="PO" />
                            </p>


                            <p>
                                <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Update" />
                            </p>
                    </form>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @LiamG not sure if I can take you or not

Comment: I'm a tad confused on what your problem is with this one? Is it the updating of the transaction that is the problem? Or creating a new one?

Comment: Updating the current one.  Lets say for example the details and department are wrong upon entry. I want to click the edit button open the update screen and it have what was orignially entered and then let me select an update the fields needed.  

The only thing is the drop downs (Fund, Department, Object Code, Project name, and budget year are all coming from tables in sql server.)   It will not allow me to add those drop downs like I did in original entry form to pull from database and update the Transaction table to show the line updated.

Comment: So on the previous page, the edit button link is something like this: `editTransaction.php?id=25`

Comment: @LiamG take a look at my answer and see what you think maybe I am not explaining it correctly

Comment: Also this script confuses me as there seems to be update and new transaction, for the sake of clarity, I would put these tasks in different scripts, I could write out some pseudo code as an answer for an edit page? Might not be very pretty but you will get the gist

Comment: so when I hit edit it knows that I want to edit that one particular transaction, and pull up that transactions information before I further edit it.

Comment: I must have something seriously wrong its giving me an error on the fourth line.

    $transaction_id = $_GET['transaction_id'];

 Undefined index: transaction_id

Comment: Are you posting the variable? Or is transaction_id in the URL?

Comment: @LiamG
thank you there was a good bit we needed to change. I actually got it working now.  I will post solution in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
require('dbcon.php');
include("header.php");
$transaction_id = $_GET['edit'];


$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $dbServer, $connectionInfo);


$sql = ("SELECT * FROM [Transaction] WHERE transaction_id = ?");
$parameters = array($transaction_id);
$MainQuery = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql,$parameters);
/*if (!sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql)) {
   die('An error has occurred. '.print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));
} else {
 echo print_r MainQuery[0];
}*/

print_r($MainQuery[0]);



while($budget2=sqlsrv_fetch_array($MainQuery,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
$ID =$budget2['transaction_id'];
$FUND =$budget2['fund'];
$DEPT =$budget2['department'];
$CODE =$budget2['code_name'];
$YEAR =$budget2['budget_year'];
$DATE =$budget2['entry_date'];
$PROJECT =$budget2['project_name'];
$DESC =$budget2['item_desc'];
$AMT =$budget2['amount'];
$DETAIL =$budget2['detail'];
$PO_NUM =$budget2['PO'];
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Update Transaction</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="form">
    <h1>Update Transaction</h1>
    <?php
    $status = "";
    if(isset($_POST['update']) && $_POST['update']==1)
    {
        $transaction_id = $_POST['transaction_id'];
        $fund = $_POST['fund'];
        $department = $_POST['department'];
        $code_name = $_POST['code_name'];
        $budget_year = $_POST['budget_year'];
        $entry_date = $_POST['entry_date'];
        $project_name = $_POST['project_name'];
        $item_desc = $_POST['item_desc'];
        $amount = $_POST['amount'];
        $detail = $_POST['detail'];
        $PO = $_POST['PO'];


         $stm = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE [Transaction] SET fund = ? , department = ? , code_name = ? , budget_year = ? , entry_date = ? , project_name = ? , item_desc = ? , amount = ? , detail = ? , PO = ?");

         $res = $stm->execute(array($fund,$department,$code_name,$budget_year,$entry_date,$project_name,$item_desc,$amount,$detail,$PO));

         if($res){
                $status = "Record Updated Successfully. </br></br>
        <a href='transactions.php'>View Updated Record</a>";
            }else{
                $status = "Record Update Failed.";
            }
            echo '<p style="color:#FF0000;">' . $status . '</p>';
        } else {
        ?> 
    <div>


        <form name="form" method="post" action=""> 

        <input type="hidden" name="update" value="1" />
        <input name="transaction_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $transaction_id;?>" />

        <p>Fund:
        <?php
            echo "<select name= 'fund' class='form-control selectpicker' onChange='getState(this.value)' Required>";

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM  Funding";
            $query_fund = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);

            while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($query_fund,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                echo $row['fund'].'=='.$FUND;
                echo '<option value=" ' . $row['fund']. '"' . ((trim($row['fund']) == trim($FUND)) ? ' selected="selected"' : "").'>'.$row['fund']. '</option>';

            //continue;
            }


        ?>
        </select>
        </p>

        <p>Department: 

    <?php

            echo "<select name= 'department' class='form-control selectpicker' onChange='getState(this.value)' Required>";

            $sql = "SELECT department FROM Department";
            $query_dept = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);

            while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($query_dept,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
            {

                echo '<option value="' . $row['department']. '"';
                if (trim($row['department']) == trim($DEPT)) {
                    echo " selected";
                }
                echo '>'.$row['department'] . '</option>' . "\n";

            }
    ?>
            </select>
        </p>


        <p>Object Code:
            <?php
            echo "<select name= 'code_name' class='form-control selectpicker' onChange='getState(this.value)' Required>";
            echo '<option value="$code_name">'.'--Select Object Code'.'</option>';
            $sql = "SELECT code_name FROM Object_Code";
            $query_code = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);

            while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($query_code,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
            echo '<option value=" ' . $row['code_name']. '"' . ((trim($row['code_name']) == trim($CODE)) ? ' selected="selected"' : "").'>'.$row['code_name']. '</option>';
            }
            ?>
            </select>
        </p>
```

Comment: Glad to see you using prepared statements!

Comment: @LiamG my Update button is not not working which is causing more issues.

Answer (score 0):

[Original Entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pglL.jpg)
[Edit Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwqYi.jpg)
Once the edit button opens I want it to open a window kind of like the original entry page so that I can choose another dept. or another drop down and update the Transaction table where the Edit button is at.

Comment: So do you need to be able to edit all the fields of the original transaction? You should edit your original question for this purpose in future

Comment: I am giving user the option to edit all fields if need be but before editing I need the fields to show what was entered first time. 
I might not have explained this in the best way.

Comment: Yeah I understand now, I'm on mobile at the moment and won't be at my pc for another 14 hours ish, I will put together a pseudo code answer and then edit it the next time I am at my PC

Comment: Sounds good thank you for all of your help.  Need to get in contact for quick answers from you .. Thank you

Comment: How do you store say 'funding' option in the transactions table? Is it with an ID? or with the name of the funding?

Comment: @LiamG its with the actual name fund - like General, Operational or Capital are the 3 options right now. The transaction_id is the primary key of the transaction table.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something along these lines, I haven't provided a full example as I really do not have the time, but you should get the idea enough to complete the rest of the code.

```
<?php
require('dbcon.php');
include("header.php");
$transaction_id = $_GET['transaction_id'];

$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM [Transaction] WHERE transaction_id = ?");
$stm->execute(array($transaction_id));
$transaction = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Update Transaction</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="form">
            <h1>Update Transaction</h1>
            <?php
            $status = "";
            if (isset($_POST['update']) && $_POST['update'] == 1) {
                $transaction_id = $_POST['transaction_id'];
                $fund = $_POST['fund'];
                $department = $_POST['department'];
                $code_name = $_POST['code_name'];
                $budget_year = $_POST['budget_year'];
                $entry_date = $_POST['entry_date'];
                $project_name = $_POST['project_name'];
                $item_desc = $_POST['item_desc'];
                $amount = $_POST['amount'];
                $detail = $_POST['detail'];
                $PO = $_POST['PO'];
                $modified = $_POST['modified'];

                $stm = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE [Transaction] SET fund = ? , department = ? , code_name = ? , budget_year = ? , entry_date = ? , project_name = ? , item_desc = ? , amount = ? , detail = ? , PO = ?");
                $res = $stm->execute(array($fund,$department,$code_name,$budget_year,$entry_date,$project_name,$item_desc,$amount,$detail,$PO));
                if($res){
                    $status = "Record Updated Successfully. </br></br>
    <a href='transactions.php'>View Updated Record</a>";
                }else{
                    $status = "Record Update Failed.";
                }
                echo '<p style="color:#FF0000;">' . $status . '</p>';
            } else {
            ?>
            <div>
                <form name="form" method="post" action=""> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="update" value="1" />
                    <input name="transaction_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $transaction['transaction_id']; ?>" />

                    <p>Fund:
                        <select name= 'fund' class='form-control selectpicker' onChange='getState(this.value)' Required>
                            <?php
                $stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM Funding");
                $stm->execute();
                $funding = $stmt->fetchAll();

                foreach($funding as $row)) {
                    $fund = $row['fund'];
                    if ($transaction['fund'] == $fund) {
                        $selected = 'selected="selected"';
                    } else {
                        $selected = "";
                    }
                    echo "<option value=\"$fund\" $selected>$fund</option>";
                }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </p>

                    <p>Department: 
                        <select name= 'department' class='form-control selectpicker' onChange='getState(this.value)' Required>
                            <?php
                $stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM Department");
                $stm->execute();
                $department = $stmt->fetchAll();
                foreach($department as $row) {
                    $department = $row['department'];
                    if ($transaction['department'] == $department) {
                        $selected = 'selected="selected"';
                    } else {
                        $selected = "";
                    }
                    echo "<option value=\"$department\" $selected>$department</option>";
                }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </p>
```

So, first off **use prepared statements**, in your old code you have this:

```
$transaction_id = $_REQUEST['transaction_id'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM [Transaction]where 
transaction_id='" . $transaction_id . "'";
```

What if the value of `$transaction_id` was `1; DROP TABLE Transactions;` ? The SQL query string you are then sending to your server would read as follows:

`SELECT * FROM [Transaction] WHERE transaction_id = 1; DROP TABLE Transactions;`

And then you would have lost all of your data, I took this basic example from [bobby-tables.com](http://bobby-tables.com/)

I would recommend using `PDO` to `prepare` and `execute` your queries in PHP, I have given you a brief taste of the syntax in my code example above.

Now, moving on from this there was a few things in your old code that didn't really make much sense, I'll try to name as many as I can;

1. You store your update query in a variable called `$update`, then execute a query using a variable called `$sql`

   ```
   $update = "update [Transaction] set 
   fund='" . $fund . "',
   department='" . $department . "',
   code_name='" . $code_name . "',
   budget_year='" . $budget_year . "',
   entry_date='" . $entry_date . "',
   project_name='" . $project_name . "',
   item_desc='" . $item_desc . "',
   amount='" . $amount . "',
   detail='" . $detail . "',
   PO='" . $PO . "'        

   where transaction_id='" . $transaction_id . "'";
               sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
   ```
2. You initially get the transaction from the DB at the start of the script and store the row in a variable called `$row`, then later on in the script do many queries for getting information for say 'Funding' all storing their results into a variable called `$row`, overwriting the transaction info. Just be more precise when naming your variables, it will make the code easier to read and also prevent errors like this.
3. In the `select` loops, you are using `echo` twice? and also testing to see if `$row['fund'] == 'Operational'` twice?

I'll finish off by explaining my code briefly, so you can finish the rest off.

First we get the transaction ID from the `$_GET` request, we use this to get the correct row from the database and store the result in an associative array name `$transaction`, so later on in the code, whenever we need information about the existing transaction we use this variable.

The update statement I just changed to a prepared statement, and added an else to display if the query had failed.

I added a closing `select` tag, as yours was missing. For both the funding and department we do the same thing, prepare a statement, fetch all the results as an array (named appropriately) and then `foreach` through them. In each iteration of the `foreach` we compare the value of the `$row` with the corresponding `$transaction` value (e.g. `$transaction['fund']==$row['fund']`) and if they match, make it selected! If they don't match then the `$selected` variable is set to be empty, and thus has no impact on the `option`.

Well this answer was longer than I expected, probably missed a lot of stuff out, but if you have any questions, leave them below!

Comment: I must have something seriously wrong its giving me an error on the fourth line.

    $transaction_id = $_GET['transaction_id'];

 Undefined index: transaction_id